# All MySQL queries involving a particular table hang

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm having trouble with a particular table in my database. I tried to update the table with an update query before and got a “lost connection to mysql server during query” response. Now I cannot do anything with the table, any queries involving the table just hang including trying to drop the table.

I've tried two possible solutions that I found. One was deleting the contents of my `sql_workspaces` folder. The other was querying with nolock. Neither worked.

Comment: I wouldn't call 3 lines rambling. Sifungurux advice helped me find the cause of my problem, I just wanted to add how i resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but it may have been locked when it lost connection in the update sequence.

Try to take a look at [SHOW LOCKED TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-open-tables.html)